# how do i get out of safe mode on htc desire s?

Tags: htc, htc-desire-s, safe-mode

Just put music on SD card, started up phone after re-inserting SD card, but it came on in 'safe mode'. Any ideas on how to switch safe mode off?

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn the phone off
2. Turn it back on and hold the <kbd>up</kbd> volume button

*Let me know if it works or not. There are also other solutions.*

[Source](http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2012/01/how-to-get-your-android-phone-out-of-safe-mode/comment-page-4/).